# Why is sending Ether cheaper TX FEE than any other erc20 coin?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, fees

I did tests with sending USDt and sending ETH. Sending ETH seems to stay around $10, while any other ERC20 coin costs me almost 3 times more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because sending ETH just costs the minimum gas fee of 21,000 for a transaction. But USDT is an ERC20 token, which means when you transfer it, you interact with a smart contract and every single instruction in the transfer function the USDT smart contract will cost some gas, on top of that base 21,000. So native currency transfer will always be cheaper than any token transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike ERC-20 smart contract `transfer()` function call, EVM has a hardcoded price for Externally Owned Account (EOA) transfers.

If you transfer ETH to a smart contract it may end up costing more.